# How to make javascript/d3 recognise date format

Tags: javascript, sorting, date

I have following code to sort dates for x axis in a scatter plot.

```
_values.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return (new Date(a)-new Date(b));
                    });
```

the dates a & b are in format mmm-yy (eg. Feb-09). But javascript recognizes the date as 9th Feb 2013 instead of 1st feb 2009. Can some one please give out a pointer as to how to sort dates for any given format. How to make javascript consider '09' as year instead of date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a legitimate date format that Javascript can understand and convert to a real Date object, which is then sortable. Please see the following documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Which points to the following date format specifications:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15

If you can convert your dates to a similar / usable format, you will be headed in the right direction.

Something else you might find useful: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/